# ¿Es posible en Android hacer que un TextView personalizado se haga clickable y/o editable por programación?

Tags: android, textview

Tengo un `TextView` personalizado que me sirve para agrandar el texto con juntar o separar los dedos (lo que se conoce como *pinch to zoom*).

Declaré este `TextView` no editable y no clickable porque en la mayoría de sitios donde lo uso sólo se requiere leer texto.

Pero ahora hay pocas Activitys donde necesito hacer uso de mi TextView Zoomable y que se pueda hacer click sobre algunos enlaces que tiene y/o editar (por editar quiero decir sobre todo copiar parte del texto tipo portapapeles para poder pegarlo en otro sitio).

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer este TextView clickable y/o editable por programación para poder reutilizarlo en esos contextos donde requiero poder hacer click?

Este es el layout de mi textView:

```
    <org.midominio.app.utils.ZoomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Zoomable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/default_font" />
```

En mi Activity lo uso así:

```
    final TextView mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
    mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(htmlContent));
```

`htmlContent` tiene algunos links y quisiera que se abran cuando el usuario pulse sobre ellos, sin tener que modificar el layout del textView.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo así:

```
    final TextView mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
            mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Mi acción
                }
            });
```

Y para lo editable (que es más para la selección de texto) en textview, mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37116712/6523745) que da skd

Espero te ayude.

> Actualizado

```
       Spanned htmlContent = Html.fromHtml("Esto es html <br />" +
                "<a href='https://www.google.com/'>vamonos a Google</a>");

        final TextView mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tv_Zoomable);
        mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        mTextView.setText(htmlContent);
```

Comment: Luis gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que yo quiero es poder hacer click sobre enlaces que aparecen en el contenido del textview y que se abra el navegador. No sé si me expliqué mal en la pregunta. El textview tiene texto vario y entre ese texto puede haber enlaces, varios enlaces. Quiero que cuando el usuario haga click en cualquiera de esos enlaces se abra el navegador por defecto del dispositivo para mostrar ese sitio web.

Comment: Listo, creo que te podría ayudar lo nuevo que agregue